# Posting to tumblr sub-blog via the API

Tags: php, api, tumblr, posting

I'm trying to use the API to post to my secondary blog and not the main one. Is that possible? 
What's the request?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the post method with your secondary blog hostname in the url?

Ex:

```
post("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/**secondary-URL.tumblr.com**/post/reblog", {:id => "XX", :reblog_key => "XXX", :state => "XXX"})
```